# Creating a CSV list from a sql table

Tags: sql, t-sql

This should be a simple one but I am having trouble with it. I want to create dynamic seperated list from a table that I have. Example:

Table:

```
Email
Person1@address.com
Person2@address.com
```

End result should give me

Person1@address.com;person2@address.com

I am not sure what the right method would be to get these results. i think that I can do it with ForXML but it is pretty complex for what seems to be a simple issue.

Any advice would be appreciated.  I will keep messing with the ForXml example I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give back the desired results:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ';'+ Email AS [text()] FROM Person FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3fac/3

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @emailstring varchar(max) = ''

select @emailstring = @emailstring + email + ';'
from tablename

set @emailstring = left(@emailstring,len(@emailstring)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using semicolons, so in `MySQL` you can do

```
select group_concat(Email SEPARATOR ';')
from   Table
```

and you're done.

Comment: Note the [tag:tsql] tag.

Comment: @JDB Good call.  I should probably turn off my GreaseMonkey script that hides offensive text whilst browsing stackexchange. :)